# Performant loading of collections of Model Data using Linq in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, entity-framework

We have controllers that read Entities with certain criteria and return a set of view models containing the data to the view. The view uses a Kendo Grid, but I don't think that makes a particular difference.

In each case, we have a Linq Query that gets the overall collection of entity rows and then a foreach loop that creates a model from each row.

Each entity has certain look ups as follows:

- those with a 1:1 relationship, e.g. Assigned to (via a foreign key to a single person)
- those with a 1:many relationship e.g. copy parties (to 0:many people - there are not many of these)
- counts of other relationships (e.g. the number of linked orders)
- any (e.g. whether any history exists)

If we do these in the model creation, the performance is not good as the queries must be run separately for each and every row.

We have also tried using includes to eager load the related entities but once you get more than two, this starts to deteriorate too.

I have seen that compiled queries and LoadProperty may be an option and I am particularly interested in the latter.

It would be great to understand best practice in these situations, so I can direct my investigations.

Thanks,

Chris.

Edit - sample code added. However, I'm looking for best practice.

```
public JsonResult ReadUsersEvents([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Guid userID)
{
    var diaryEventModels = new List<DiaryEventModel>();
    var events = UnitOfWork.EventRepository.All().Where(e => e.UserID == userID);
    foreach (var eventItem in events)
    {
        var diaryModel = new DiaryEventModel(eventItem);
        diaryEventModels.Add(diaryModel);
    }
    var result = diaryEventModels.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public DiaryEventModel(Event eventItem) {

    // Regular property from Entity examples - no issue here as data retrived simply in original query
    ID = eventItem.ID;
    Start = eventItem.StartDateTime;
    End = eventItem.EndDateTime;
    EventDescription = eventItem.Description;

    // One to one looked up Property example
    eventModel.Creator = eventItem.Location.FullName;

    // Calculation example based on 0 to many looked up properties, also use .Any in some cases
    // This is a simplified example
    eventModel.AttendeeCount = eventItem.EventAttendees.Count();

    // 0 to Many looked up properties
    EventAttendees = eventItem.EventAttendees.Select(e => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = e.Person.FullName,
            Value = e.Person.ID.ToString()
        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with some code to complete the whole picture?

Comment: I would strongly suspect that .All() method.. what does it do?  I'd also get rid of the useless UnitOfWork, which is a worst practice when using an ORM that already supports UoW such as EF, unless you have very specific needs (such as unifying disparate data sets in a single UoW).  My guess is that you're returning IEnumerable's rather than Expressions, which will cause all records to be returned.